# main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml' What is the role of this line configuration?

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I took over a project.

There is a line `main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'` in the gradle configuration.

It will cause Lint to report an error.

Can anyone explain the meaning of this line configuration for me?

Comment: Normally it's to add extra source directories to the project, but that's not what it's doing here, and it won't work. Remove that line.

Comment: @TheWanderer Thank you very much, this is really an invalid configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

main.java.srcDirs is a collection.you can set like follow code or just delele it(if you don't really need set it by yourself)

```
main.java.srcDirs = ['src/main','src/other/xxx']
```

Comment: I think this is a one-line error and invalid configuration because it causes my APK to fail to generate